# While Working on Wordpress with elementor pro i got an following eroor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Warning: Undefined array key "license" in C:\xampp\htdocs\nsuwrc\wp-content\plugins\elementor-pro-master\license\api.php on line 361

Comment: What’s your question, exactly? [ask]

Comment: Please ask a proper question.  Warnings are not errors per se.

Answer (score 1):

Good evening. I don't want to assume any questions but wanted to point you to some advice.

Sometimes third party plugins omit warnings in Wordpress that are visible on the front end. You could possibly have your error_reporting setting for your PHP configuration set for a higher verbose level.

If your question would be how can you suppress this message please check your `php.ini` configuration file for the currently set error_reporting level.

If you are looking into removing warnings you can turn off that type of verbose with the error_reporting flag. (`E_ERROR` instead of `E_WARNING`)

You can learn more with the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

I hope this information is helpful for you.